# How to plot a decision boundary of random forest model

Tags: r, plot, random-forest, decision-tree

I have

```
## Classification:
library("randomForest")
data=iris
data<-data[data$Species!="setosa",]
data$Species<-factor(as.character(data$Species))
iris.rf <- randomForest(Species ~ Sepal.Length+Petal.Length, data=data, importance=TRUE,            proximity=TRUE)
```

I would like to construct a `Sepal.Length~Petal.Length` with the decision boundary. And what kind of boundary will this be? 0.5 probability for each of the 2 classes?

Answer (score 1):

You have a random forest, so there is not necessarily a clear decision boundary like you would get from a non-probabilistic linear classifier like SVM.  But you could plot it with something like...

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=data,aes(x=Petal.Length, y=Sepal.Length, color= iris.rf$predicted) ) + 
       geom_point()
```

[image]

And in this case yes, since you trained it only on two classes, the boundary represented by the color change happens at 0.5.

Comment: if you feed the RF model newdata=data.frame(expand.grid(Sepal.Length=seq(5,8,0.1), Petal.Length=seq(3,7,0.1))) shouldnt you be able to get a decision boundary on the Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length plane?

Comment: Are you trying to get something that looks like the third figure [here](https://shapeofdata.wordpress.com/2013/07/09/random-forests/)?

Comment: If the axis x and y are the 2 independent variables of the RF model, yes.